# Regex to split string by whitespace OR minus signs in C#

Tags: regex, string, split

I have a string with a list of temperatures that can be in the negatives or positives.

Some of these temperatures will be separated by a whitespace, while some won't be.

i.e.:   `19 20 22 -1 -3-4-10 -7 2 10`

And I want to split that string by keeping only the values as such:

```
19
20
22
-1
-3
-4
-10
-7
2
10
```

Can anyone help me with that? I am not experienced with regular expressions.

Thank you VERY much in advance!

Cheers

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split according to the below regex.

```
@"\s+|(?<!\s)(?=-)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wT0iY3/4)

ie,

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(input_str, @"\s+|(?<!\s)(?=-)");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```
  (?!-)|(?=-)
```

check this demo [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX1zG3/2)

```
string temperatures = "19 20 22 -1 -3-4-10 -7 2 10";

string[] res = Regex.Split(temperatures, " (?!-)|(?=-)");

foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

#19
#20
#22
#-1
#-3
#-4
#-10
#-7
#2
#10
```